# Using WITH together with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE AS SELECT ... in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, temporary-tables

I would like to create a temporary table using a select statement that uses temporary views specified in a WITH statement (not the WITH statement of CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE).

e.g. something along the lines of

```
WITH a AS (
SELECT 1 foo, 2 bar 
), b AS (
SELECT 4 bar, 5 baz
)
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo AS
SELECT * from a JOIN b ON (a.bar=b.bar)
```

If I comment out the CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE line, this works. How to create a temporary table using the query result of the SELECT, without rewriting the temporary views into a single query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The WITH goes after the CREATE TABLE

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo 
AS
WITH a AS (
SELECT 1 foo, 2 bar 
), b AS (
SELECT 4 bar, 5 baz
)
SELECT * from a JOIN b ON (a.bar=b.bar)
```

Note the above will result in "ERROR: column "bar" specified more than once" - but I assume you are using better (distinct) column names in the real query.

Comment: @peschü: The simple way to resolve the duplicate column name in the example: `... SELECT * from a JOIN b USING (bar);`

Comment: Thank you! I could not find this in the Postgres documentation but I thought it should be possible. It works! (if I replace the * by something more reasonable) :-)